# Watin Recorder v2 couldn't rerun the test

Tags: c#, debugging, watin

When I tried to create a Web application test and record it with the Watin Test Recorder v2.
For example: 
1) go to google.com page
2) Input "Hollywood" in the search box
3) Click Google Search
4) Click on the first result

The Recorder could actually records the actions, I can see all the steps and description clearly and have no problem extracting C# code from it

However, when I tried to re-run the test, what it could do only:
- Navigate to the google.com page and hang there with the empty search box!!
- Also tried to put some break points to debug but couldnt find out the root of the issue.

Any one have ever faced this problem before, could give me an advise??

Thankss

Comment: Yes, I did. This isn't quite the correct question format, however... websites could change slightly from visit to visit. Maybe watin doesn't find the part it's looking for, didn't it throw any exception?

Comment: @Gabber hi, which version of Test Recorder are you using, could you provide me download link also? Thankss